# PHP CodeIgniter to PhoneGap android app

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, cordova

I have heard about PhoneGap that can convert Web based app into a mobile app. I was wondering if PhoneGap can "convert" php codeigniter web based app into a mobile one..? I've also heard about Titanium software that does something similar... I wouldn't want to rewrite whole app to make it usable on android devices.. Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: It can compile `HMTL5` web apps to native apps, `PHP` will not work in this scenario.

Comment: That's not encouraging.... Thanks Novocaine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap just make use of web tech, such as  js, css, html. It 'convert' it to mobile apps. You can interact with server side which is use php, asp, jsp or other server side script use ajax.

hopely useful: http://www.indiageeks.in/phonegap-jquery-ajax-example-jsonjavascript-object-notation-response/